# Tray in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, tray

Trying to find out how to reference my Tray object. It has been created, but for some reason, I cannot seem to find out how to call it for reference. Trying via dev console... 
`require('electron').remote.Tray`

This seems to get the native function for Tray... I have tried `remote.getTray()` and a few others.. I am using  [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue). Here is my `electron.js` setup.

```
'use strict'

 const electron = require('electron')
 const path = require('path')
 const app = electron.app
 const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
 var {Menu, Tray} = require('electron')

 let tray = null
 app.on('ready', () => {
   tray = new Tray(__dirname + '\\icons\\twitch.ico')
   const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
     {label: 'Item1', type: 'radio'},
     {label: 'Item2', type: 'radio'},
     {label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true},
     {label: 'Item4', type: 'radio'}
   ]);
   tray.setToolTip('Welcome')
   tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
 })
 ...
```

I do not know how to reference it correctly.  [Here is the Tray Documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/tray/) 
My ultimate goal is to use some of the ***Instance Methods*** (located in the Tray Documentation)

 

Thanks!

Comment: "This seems to get the native function for Tray" - Have you tried adding `()` after it to call that function then?

Comment: Yes, no return. It requires a constructor I believe

Comment: The Tray init (new Tray) does not support .ico, try using .jpg or .png instead.

Comment: My Tray does appear with the ICO file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` for the interaction between your UI and your Electron instance.

Let's say you wrote the following in the `*.vue` file:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
.....
.....
ipcRenderer.on('interactionSignalFromUI');
```

Then again in the `electron.js` setup you need to simply call: